# SqlDataReader GetChar(int index) method

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

Specified in MSDN:

[MSDN - SqlDataReader GetChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getchar%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
Except that method is marked with

`[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]`

attribute and while you can code -> compile it, when you run the method it throws a "method not supported" exception.

Is there any way to then read a single char from a reader without using the (buffer required) GetChars method or reading it in as a string and then getting the [0] character?

(Also, shouldn't those methods be either hidden or marked with something on MSDN stating you shouldn't use them?)

EDIT:

As pointed out by Daniel A. White, down in the remarks section there's a single line saying the method is not supported for SqlClient.

Comment: its marked that its not supported.

Comment: I'd avoid the issue by using `GetString(index).First()`

Comment: What type do you get when you just call GetValue? If its a string there then just use GetString. Nothing to win when you try something different.

Comment: It has been 6 years and this `insert a bad word here` still bugs my code. I couldn't find what was causing the problem for a good hour because there were some indirected catch blocks. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I could have used:

`reader.GetString(colIndex)[0]`

I instead opted for:

```
var buffer = new char[1];
reader.GetChars(colIndex, 0, buffer, 0, 1);
```

Comment: Boxing/ Unboxing:
"Boxing is the process of converting a value type to the type object or to any interface type implemented by this value type. When the CLR boxes a value type, it wraps the value inside a System.Object and stores it on the managed heap. Unboxing extracts the value type from the object. Boxing is implicit; unboxing is explicit. The concept of boxing and unboxing underlies the C# unified view of the type system in which a value of any type can be treated as an object. " https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Because `SqlDataReader` implements `IDataReader`, it has a `GetChar()` method. But on `SqlDataReader`, the *implementation* of that is just to throw a `NotImplementedException`. `SqlDataReader` is marked so as to not offer `GetChar()` in the intellisense, although if you type in `GetChar()` onto the end of a `SqlDataReader`, you'll see that it compiles but at runtime you get the `NotImplementedException`.

All rather disappointing, as it seems to me that it would only have taken a few lines of code for the .Net team to have implemented `GetChar()`.

Happily, by using extension methods, we can add our own `GetChar()` method to `SqlDataReader`. As `GetChar()` is taken already (although only implemented with a `NotImplmentedException`), we have to call it something other than `GetChar()`. I called it `GetSingleChar()`:

```cs
internal static class ExtensionMethods
{
    internal static char GetSingleChar(this SqlDataReader reader, int columnIndex)
    {
        System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlChars val = reader.GetSqlChars(columnIndex);
        if (val.Length != 1)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(
                "Expected value to be 1 char long, but was "
                + val.Length.ToString() + " chars long.");
        }
        return val[0];
    }
}
```